# Bower error ansi-styles when using Yeoman Ember

Tags: ember.js, yeoman, bower

I tried following the directions to get Yeoman Ember started from here:

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-ember#usage

```
npm install -g generator-ember
mkdir myemberapp && cd myemberapp
yo ember
npm install -g grunt-mocha
grunt serve

A welcome page should appear in your browser.
```

However, Bower errors out withe the following error

```
..\myemberapp>bower install

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Usr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bowe
r\node_modules\chalk\chalk.js:2:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Thanks for any leads!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Bower. It's corrupt as it's missing a dependency.

Comment: Tried reinstall everything, including npm, with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install ansi-styles:

```
npm install -g ansi-styles
```

If you just end up having the next dependency missing there is probably something inherently wrong that needs fixed, and someone smarter than me needs to help you.